# How to pip-install Python package into virtual env and have CLI commands accessible in normal shell

Tags: python, path, pip, command-line-interface, virtualenv

For larger Python packages which might interfere with other packages it is recommended to install them into their own virtual environment and some Python packages expose CLI commands to the shell.

Is there a way to pip-install such a package into its own virtual environment,
but have the CLI commands accessible from a normal shell *without* switching
beforehand manually to this virtual environment?

Here an example: When I install **[csvkit](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit)** via

```
pip install csvkit
```

I have the commands `csvcut`, `csvlook`, `csvgrep` and others available in my
shell. However if I do not want to install **cvskit** in my System-Python and
install it in a virtual environment, say at `~/venvs/csvkit`, I have
**csvkit** only available if I have manually activated the environment
`csvkit`.

Is there a way to create the virtual environment and install **csvkit** in it,
so that the commands like `csvcut` activate the environment themselves before
they run?

Comment: After reading [the first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43137971/65889) I realise the best would be if the **python code** could activate the necessary environment - then argument handling etc would work like normal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A newer tool which still is very well maintained is [pipx - Install and Run Python Applications in Isolated Environments](https://github.com/pipxproject/pipx). It works similar to pipsi:

1. First install `pipx`. (See [pipx installation](https://pipxproject.github.io/pipx/installation/))
2. Then issue:

   ```
   pipx install csvkit
   ```
3. Finally make sure `pipx`'s bin directory (normally `~/.local/bin`) is in your PATH.

Please note, pipx has additional commands for maintaining and inspecting of the generated venvs - see `pipx --help`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an aliases, such as `csvcut` and point them to `source ~/venvs/csvkit/bin/activate && csvcut && source deactivate`

If this programs accept parameters, you can use functions and defined the in the `.bashrc` file:

```
csvcut() {
    #do things with parameters like $1 such as
    source ~/venvs/csvkit/bin/activate
    csvcut $1 $2 $3 $4 $5
    deactivate
}
```

To call the function, just use the `csvcut <your_parameter>` command.

Comment: Not a bad idea! But it doesn't work: Firstly `deactivate` is not a script. And secondly, more problematic, `csvcut` for example has lots of different numbers of arguments it can take...

Comment: I edited the answer so it could take even 5 arguments... and fixed the deactivate, my bed...

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pipsi`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/pipsi). Here a description from the project's ReadMe:

> pipsi installs each package into ~/.local/venvs/PKGNAME and then symlinks all new scripts into ~/.local/bin (these can be changed by PIPSI_HOME and PIPSI_BIN_DIR env variables respectively).
>
> Compared to pip install --user each PKGNAME is installed into its own virtualenv, so you don't have to worry about different `PKGNAME`s having conflicting dependencies.

It works a treat for `csvkit`:

1. First install `pipsi`.
2. Then issue:

   ```
    pipsi install csvkit
   ```
3. Finally make sure `pipsi`'s bin directory (normally `~/.local/bin`) is in your PATH.

That's it! Now you can type on the comamnd line e.g.

```
csvcut --help
```

which calls `csvcut` in its own virtualenv.

There's is no need to manually activate an virtualenv and your system Python does not get polluted by additional packages (apart from the `pipsi` package once and for all).